# Implemeting third-party ios plugin to unity problems

Tags: ios, plugins, uiview, unity-game-engine

i'm currently trying to implement a ios plugin in my unity application. The plugin is a simple one that it shows another view in the app showing social media and stuff.

I'm doing this the plugin way, setup a button that has click methods calling extern in c# code to call the objective-c code.

In the objective-c code, i have tried several ways :

The first way :

1. i created a custom view controller that add itself to the [[[Application sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:customViewController.view]
2. and in the plugins i set the custom view controller as the delegate to catch the plugins dismiss event
3. I called the plugins on the view did load. the plugins view showed up fine, and i got the dismiss event. In the dismiss event, i called [self.removeFromSuperview]. The plugins then disappears from view however i couldn't get my unity to respond to my input (like there's still another layer in front of unity layer)

The second way :

Almost the same like the first way, but in the custom view controller i add a nib with a button to open the plugin view [[lugin displayView] and another button to close the view [self.view removefromsuperview]. The plugin showed up and closed just fine and unity received my controls, but the ui orientation of the button is set to potrait while my unity application is set to landscape right. The plugin view is somehow changed itself to landscape right.

The third way :

I modified the appcontroller.mm , adding my own view controller containing my plugin view and the eaglview. The plugin showed up and the unity can received input but the orientation of the plugin is potrait..

Does anyone can point out to me which approach must i focused on / did I miss something ? Thanks before ! :)